# Default Directory Index

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a website :

http://www.exclusivetech.net/clients/fashion/

If you look at the url then i have not mention any page/file name to be executed, it will display index.php bydefault.. I want it to show page not found error against this and any sub directory if particular filename is not mentioned in any URL .....

Comment: Maybe you should add here you .htaccess file to let people modify it

Answer (score 1):

Write this in your .htaccess

```
    ErrorDocument 404 /path/to/yourerrorpage.html
```

Comment: i am using htaccess only for this purpose .. so this one line will work ??

Comment: It should work, have you replaced `/path/to/yourerrorpage.html` with the real path to your error page?